# Possible to programmatically pause/resume Azure's Application Gateway with Web Application Firewall status/billing?

Tags: azure

I'd like to perform R&D testing on the Azure Application Gateway with Web Application Firewall (AG-WAF), but just for two hours per day, but I don't want to pay for 24x7.

Is there anyway to programmatically start/pause/stop the AG-WAF for just two hours each day to pause the billing or must I terminate it and rebuild it each day to pause the billing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use powershell, take a look on the following commands:

Start-AzureRmApplicationGateway : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/start-azurermapplicationgateway?view=azurermps-6.13.0

Stop-AzureRmApplicationGateway : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azurerm.network/stop-azurermapplicationgateway?view=azurermps-6.13.0